# Defining Contravariant add method on Immutable Stack in Java

Tags: java, immutability, contravariance

I've been trying to define an immutable ConsList in Java, somewhat like how Lists work in Scala. Each prepending creates a new view of the list (starting with the new head) and returns it. Here's what I have so far, which all compiles and runs correctly.

```
package common.dataStructures;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * An immutable collection representing a Cons List.
 * All Cons Lists are terminated with a Nil element (no tail, no value),
 * but this element is hidden from iteration and stringing when there
 * are non-nil elements in the list.
 * <br><br>
 * Because the List is immutable, different lists can be branched off of a shared
 * tail without altering the tail. This makes the ConsList useful in some algorithms
 * that require exploring different possibility chains without altering earlier
 * sub-chains.
 *
 * @param <E> - the generic type of elements stored within the lst.
 *            No methods are ever called on elements of type E, so no requirements
 *            are made of the type.
 * @author Mshnik
 */
public class ConsList<E> implements Iterable<E> {

  /**
   * A string used for toString implementations for the Nil element of
   * a Cons List
   */
  public static final String NIL_STRING = "_NIL_";

  /**
   * The tail of this List.
   * If this is Nil, tail is null. Otherwise, this is another ConsList
   * of one smaller size.
   */
  private final ConsList<E> tail;

  /**
   * The value stored in the head of this list.
   * If this is Nil, value is null. Otherwise the value may be null,
   * or the value stored in the head.
   */
  public final E val;

  /**
   * The size of this list. Because ConsLists are immutable, this size
   * value is immutable. If this is Nil, size is 0. Otherwise, size
   * is some positive, non-zero value
   */
  public final int size;

  /**
   * Initializes an empty (NIL) ConsList, with tail = null, val = null,
   * size = 0. <br>
   * A Nil element is required to be at the end of every ConsList,
   * so this constructor is used to start any ConsList. Elements are then
   * cons (prepended) on to this element to build a list.
   */
  public ConsList() {
    val = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new head of a list
   *
   * @param val  - the value to store in the head of this list
   * @param tail - the tail of this list, an existing ConsList
   * @param size - the size of this list
   */
  private ConsList(E val, ConsList<E> tail, int size) {
    this.val = val;
    this.size = size;
    this.tail = tail;
    if (val == null || tail == null || size < 1)
      throw new RuntimeException("Illegal ConsList construction" + this);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value stored in the head of this ConsList
   */
  public E value() {
    return val;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the tail of this ConsList. Returns null if this is NIL
   */
  public ConsList<E> tail() {
    return tail;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if this is NIL - the trailing element in a consList.
   * A Nil element has no tail and no value
   */
  public boolean isNil() {
    return tail() == null && val == null;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if this is the last element in a list.
   * Returns true for NIL elements, and the last real element before a NIL element
   * Used to stop iteration before it reaches the NIL terminator
   */
  public boolean isLast() {
    return isNil() || tail().tail() == null && tail().val == null;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a new ConsList that consists of {@code head} prepended
   * onto this ConsList
   */
  public ConsList<E> cons(E head) {
    return new ConsList<E>(head, this, size + 1);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a new ConsList that consists of this full list, reversed.
   */
  public ConsList<E> reverse() {
    ConsList<E> reversed = new ConsList<E>();
    ConsList<E> ptr = this;
    while (!ptr.isNil()) {
      reversed = reversed.cons(ptr.val);
      ptr = ptr.tail;
    }
    return reversed;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a string representation of a ConsList
   */
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String s = "(";
    ConsList<E> current = this;
    while (current != null) {
      if (current.val == null && current.tail() == null) {
        if (current == this) s += NIL_STRING + ",";
      } else {
        s += current.val + ",";
      }
      current = current.tail();
    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length() - 1) + ")";
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if this equals {@code o}.
   * Two ConsLists are equal if they are the same length and every value they
   * at each index are equal.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof ConsList<?>) || o == null) return false;

    ConsList<?> lst = (ConsList<?>) o;

    return size == lst.size && Objects.equals(val, lst.val) && Objects.equals(tail(), lst.tail());
  }

  /**
   * Returns the size of this list. See {@link common.dataStructures.ConsList#size}
   */
  public int size() {
    return size;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true iff the size of this list is 0. Equivalently, if this list is NIL
   */
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true iff this list contains the Object o.
   * NIL lists do not contain any elements, thus calling contains on a NIL
   * list for any input will always return false.
   */
  public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return !isNil() && (Objects.equals(val, o) || !isLast() && tail().contains(o));
  }

  /**
   * Returns true iff, for all {@code Object o : c}, this.contains(o)
   */
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object o : c) {
      if (!contains(o)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns an Iterator over the elements in this ConsList.
   * As ConsLists are immutable, the returned iterator does not support removal,
   * and cannot throw a ConcurrentModificationException.
   * The iterator returned will stop at the last real element in the list,
   * *before* the NIL element that terminates all lists. If this method
   * is called on the NIL list, the iterator will have no elements to return -
   * hasNext() will immediately return false. Thus the iterator behaves as if
   * the NIL element does not exist.
   */
  @Override
  public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new ConsIterator<E>(this);
  }

  /**
   * Converts this ConsList to an array of Objects.
   * The length of the returned array is equal to this.size.
   * Therefore for the NIL array, the returned array is of length 0.
   */
  public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] arr = new Object[size];
    ConsList<E> current = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, current = current.tail()) {
      arr[i] = current.val;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  /**
   * Converts this ConsList to an array of type T.
   * The length of the returned array is equal to Max(this.size, arr.length).
   * Therefore for the NIL array, the returned array is of length 0.
   * See the List interface for the weird type bullcrap about casting to T[]
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < size) {
      arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, size);
    }
    ConsList<E> current = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, current = current.tail()) {
      arr[i] = (T) current.val;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the {@code index}th element in this list.
   *
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException - if index &lt; 0 or index &gt;= size - thus throws
   * exception if this is called with any index value on the nil list
   */
  public E get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't get element at index " + index + " OOB");

    if (index == 0) return val;
    return tail().get(index - 1);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the first index of {@code o} in this List, or -1 if it does not occur
   */
  public int indexOf(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Helper method for the indexOf function - keeps track of how many recursive
   * calls have been made thus far to this function to return the correct value
   * if {@code o} is found.
   */
  private int indexOf(Object o, int x) {
    if (Objects.equals(val, o)) return x;
    else if (isLast()) return -1;
    return tail().indexOf(o, x + 1);
  }

  /**
   * Helper class for iterating over ConsList
   * Keeps track of a current list element that will be returned by next() calls.
   *
   * @param <E>
   * @author Mshnik
   */
  public static class ConsIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private ConsList<E> current; //next element to return when next() is called

    /**
     * Creates a new ConsIterator, starting at first
     */
    public ConsIterator(ConsList<E> first) {
      current = first;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true iff there is another element to iterate over.
     * Specifically, returns {@code !current.isNil()}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return !current.isNil();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next value in this iteration, and moves current
     * forward one element.
     */
    @Override
    public E next() {
      E val = current.val;
      current = current.tail();
      return val;
    }

  }

}
```

This all works for type `E` and covartiants thereof. If I have a `ConsList<Animal>`, and I call `cons(new Dog())`, it will give me a `ConsList<Animal>`, as desired.

However, I've tried every what I can think of to define a contravariant cons method. My best guess looks roughly like this:

```
public <X super E> ConsList<X> cons(X head) {
    return new ConsList(head, this, size+1);
}
```

Which I would hope would allow me to create a `ConsList<String>`, cons on `new Object` and receive a `ConsList<Object>`.

But this approach doesn't compile, nor does any other attempt I've made. I understand why mutable data structures (i.e. `ArrayList`) do not support covariance or contravariance, but is there any syntactically valid way to define generic contravariance in Java, even for immutable structures? If so, what is it, and if not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Remark: This is not a complete answer, but it gives an idea how to solve it by pushing some checks to runtime and adding the class-information.
The other question about 'why', i can't answer.

You need to pass an object and the class of the object. Your compiler will here throw an exception if the class is not `super E`. Although the check if head is really an instance of clazz needs to be done manually.

```
public <T> ConsList<T> cons(final T head, final Class<? super E> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(head) && head.getClass().equals(clazz)) {
        return new ConsList(head, this, this.size + 1);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("T is not instance of class");
    }
}
```

It is not size as you need to pass the class. But at least you can call it like:

```
list.cons(headElement, headElement.getClass());
```